# Why clicking links on the news feed wants authorization from users

Tags: facebook, post, hyperlink, authorization

I make an application on Facebook to send post to the account of mine from my web page.
So I succeed it using Facebook C# SDK. 
[Here is an image of my post](http://cdn3.hazirportal.com/files/hazirportal.com/yuklenenicerik/facebook-news-feed-1.png)

But When I clicked the link of the post, Facebook direct me to the Authorization page of my Facebook app. And after I click the skip button or allow button, I go to the my web page I posted. 
[Here is an image of authorization page](http://cdn3.hazirportal.com/files/hazirportal.com/yuklenenicerik/facebook-news-feed-2.png)

I realize that some other apps posts don't let me authorization if I click of their links.
Like this. When I click its title I go to the web page they share. It is also a post message and sent from a Facebook application not sharing a link.

So. How can I prevent the users that click my post go to authorization page of my application. This users don't belong to my Facebook app. they are my friends.

Thanks